# Why this Prolog code does not work?

Tags: prolog

i have a prolog code that finds Kth element of a given list.

this code doesnt work.

```
element_at(X,[X|_],1) :- !.

element_at(X,[_|T],K) :-  element_at(X,T,K-1).
```

but when i modified this code a little bit, then works.

```
element_at(X,[X|_],1) :- !.

element_at(X,[_|T],K) :-  K1 is K-1,element_at(X,T,K1).
```

why we need such a thing like K1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass an expression such as `K-1` as an argument to a predicate in prolog, prolog does not evaluate the expression as in other languages. It's passed as the term `'-'(K,1)` with `K` instantiated as indicated in your predicate.

So, let's suppose you queried:

```
element_at(X, [1,2], 2).
```

Then your query would match the second clause of your predicate:

```
element_at(X,[_|T],K) :- element_at(X,T,K-1).
```

And recursively query:

```
element_at(X, [2], 2-1).
```

This would match the second clause again and query:

```
element_at(X, [], 2-1-1).
```

Which will fail since it doesn't match any of your clauses.

Therefore, if you want to pass the value of an expression as an argument, you need to pre-evaluate, as you have done with `K1`:

```
K1 is K-1,
element_at(X, T, K1).
```

Note that you could have a deferred evaluation. For example:

```
foo(X, Y) :-
    Y is X * 2.

| ?- X = 1, foo(X-3, Y).

X = 1
Y = -4

yes
| ?-
```

In this case, when `foo` is queried, it queries as, `foo(1-3, Y)`. When `foo` executes, it executes the line: `Y is X * 2` which evaluates, `Y is (1-3)*2` yielding `Y=-4`.